# Tinymce broken if hidden en shown by jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, tinymce

I'm using tinymce on a textfield in a form.
I want to hide the form by default so i hide it with jquery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#hidediv").hide();

  $("#tiny").click(function(){
    $("#hidediv").show();
  });
});
</script>
```

However, the textfield is kinda broken if i hide it like this, it's using tiny, but the toolbar is missing.
(see screenshot)
[missing toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsmAj.png)

If i drag the textfield to be bigger, the toolbar appears, but outside of the textfield, breaking the layout.
[Toolbar appears breaking layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZr24.png)

If i however, resize the window, the problem is gone, and the tinymce editor behaves normally.
[After rezise window, no problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zKqs.png)

What am i doing wrong?

No idea what to try, i googled but answers are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that i need to initialize the editor on the onclick.

This fixed my issue

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#divtohide").hide();    
                           
  $("#button").click(function() {                
    $('#divtohide').show();
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#textarea_id',
      height: 500
    });
  });
});
```